# List available VM SKUs for the azure policy "Allowed virtual machine SKUs"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

```
$definition = Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object {$_.Properties.DisplayName -eq "Allowed virtual machine SKUs"}

New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'Test' -DisplayName 'Test' -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceID -PolicyDefinition $definition
```

Running this command will ask for 'listOfAllowedSKUs' for which SKUs i want to allow to be created in the specified resource group. I can find a list of them by going into the azure portal, finding policy and clicking assign policy, then selecting "Allowed virtual machine skus" and then going into parameters and looking at the names.

I can type in those names manually one by one when i get asked for it after running the command, but instead of opening the azure portal every time, i want to be able to list the available SKUs in powershell instead. I can't find anything online about getting a list of available SKUs in the console.

Is is possible to get a list of available SKUs to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you want to get the SKUs corresponding to a specific Location, Publisher and Offer, you may use the [Get-AzVMImageSku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Compute/Get-AzVMImageSku?view=azps-3.3.0) cmdlet to get the VMImage SKUs by providing the Location, PublisherName and Offer as input parameters, and then construct the `AllowedSkus` object. For example:

```
$sku = Get-AzVMImageSku -Location "Central US" -PublisherName "Fabrikam" -Offer "LinuxServer"
$AllowedSkus = @{'listOfAllowedSKUs'=($sku.Skus)}
```

Else, to mimic the list of available SKUs as appearing in the portal, you may use the [Get-AzVMSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmsize?view=azps-3.3.0) cmdlet to get the available virtual machine sizes as follows:

```
$allsizes = Get-AzLocation | Get-AzVmSize | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
$AllowedSkus = @{'listOfAllowedSKUs'=($allsizes)}
```

This can finally be passed to the `New-AzPolicyAssignment` cmdlet using the `-PolicyParameterObject` option:

```
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name '<policy assignment name>' -DisplayName '<display name>' -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceID -PolicyDefinition $definition -PolicyParameterObject $AllowedSkus
```

Other examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-3.3.0#description). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if you want to know the available virtual machine SKUs in the subscription, you can use the following PowerShell command

```
Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where{$_.ResourceType.Equals('virtualMachines')}| fl
```

Its outputs contain parameter [Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list#resourcesku). The parameter will tell us which SKU cannot be used.
For example

- Giving one type of restriction : Zone Type for size Standard_A0 which means that under a particular subscription, Standard_A0 is not available to be created in West Europe region if placed in Availability Zones

[image]

- Giving no Restrictions at the end, which means that VM Size : Standard_F8s can be created under this particular subscription in this region : West Europe without any restrcitions ( i.e : it can be created with Availaibility Zone and without Availaibility zone as well )

[image]

- Giving two types of restrictions : Zone Type and Location Type, which means that VM Size of Standard_DS2_V2_Promo cannot be created in this particular subscription in this region : WestEurope at all.

[image]